# bugs in my card game simulation script

Tags: python, simulation

I know its frowned upon to ask questions like this here but i cant seem to work out all the bugs out of my python script. it simulates a game of war (card game). it should work perfectly, i think. I would really appreciate if someone that knew more python than me would look at my script and try, basically, to fix it.

```
import random

cards = ['ace', 'ace', 'ace', 'ace', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '10', '10', '10', '10', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'jack', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen', 'king', 'king', 'king', 'king']

order = ['ace', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king'] 
warcardvalue0 = 0
warcardvalue1 = 0
print "shuffling cards" 
cards = random.shuffle(cards,random.random)
print "lets play"
player0 = [cards[i] for i in range(len(cards)) if i % 2 == 1]

player1 = [cards[i] for i in range(len(cards)) if i % 2 == 0]

while (len(player0) > 0 or len(player1) > 0):

    nextcard0 = player0[0]
    nextcard1 = player1[0]

    cardplayed0 = order.index(nextcard0)

    cardplayed1 = order.index(nextcard1)

    if cardplayed0 > cardplayed1:

        player0.append(nextcard0)
        player0.append(nextcard1)
        player0.remove(nextcard0)
        player1.remove(nextcard1)

    elif cardplayed0 < cardplayed1:

        player1.append(nextcard1)
        player1.append(nextcard0)
        player1.remove(nextcard1)
        player0.remove(nextcard0)

    elif cardplayed0 == cardplayed1:
        while warcardvalue0 == warcardvalue1:
            if len(player0) >= 4:
                warcard0 = 4
            elif len(player0) < 4:
                warcard0 = len(player0)

            if len(player1) >= 4:
                warcard1 = 4
            elif len(player1) < 4:
                warcard1 = len(player1)


            warcardvalue0 = order.index(warcard0)
            warcardvalue1 = order.index(warcard1)

            if warcardvalue0 > warcardvalue1:
                player0.append(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)])
                player0.append(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)])
                player0.remove(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)])
                player1.remove(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)])

            elif warcardvalue0 < warcardvalue1:
                player1.append(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)])
                player1.append(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)])
                player1.remove(player1[range(warcard1 + 1)])
                player0.remove(player0[range(warcard0 + 1)]) 
            else:
                print "another war!" 


if len(player1) == 0:
    print "player1 won!"
elif len(player0) == 0:
    print "player0 won!"
```

Comment: What isn't working right in particular?

Comment: well because the code is executed differently every time, because of the card "shuffling" there are many different errors. Basically there are a lot of bugs many of which i don't even know about

Comment: @A.Collins: How about starting with the ones that you do know of? Throw us a bone. Try commenting out the shuffling code so you have a repeatable test.

Comment: Use `random.seed` to force the program to shuffle the same way each time it is run. That should help you track down bugs related to specific arrangements.

Comment: Well, @A.Collins?  You've had this question out for almost an hour and haven't added anything, despite plenty of suggestions to improve the question.  That's kind of rude don't you think?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more pythonic or at least clearer to define `cards` as: `cards = ['ace'] * 4  + ['1'] * 4 + ['2'] * 4 + ...`? Since you are shuffling it, you could pretend it's a new deck from a pack and do `cards = ['ace', '1', '2', ...]` and then `cards = cards * 4` to give you `['ace', '1', '2', ..., 'ace', '1', '2', ..., 'ace', '1', '2', ..., 'ace', '1', '2']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, I think you're going to want

```
warcardvalue0 = order.index(warcard0)
warcardvalue1 = order.index(warcard1)
```

To be

```
warcardvalue0 = order.index(player0[warcard0])
warcardvalue1 = order.index(player1[warcard1])
```

So you're getting the actual value of the war card, and not the number 4.

You may also want to do:

```
        elif len(player1) < 4:
            warcard1 = len(player1)-1
```

instead of:

```
        elif len(player1) < 4:
            warcard1 = len(player1)
```

So you're not running off the end of your arrays.

You should also be incrementing your war card values, instead of setting them statically, so that multiple layered wars can be fought.  For readability's sake, you might consider a recursive function.  Or this:

```
        if len(player0) >= warcard0 + 4:
            warcard0 = warcard0+3
        elif len(player0) < warcard0 + 4:
            warcard0 = len(player0)-1
```

(remember, arrays are zero based, so index 3 actually returns the fourth element)

And I think you're looking for a slice at the end there:

```
            player1.append(player1[0:warcard1+1])
```

You also don't consider the case where one player runs out of cards during the war, and another war ensues. (Where the war cards are equal, but one player has no more).  Though I think this will be solved if you solve the previous issues, albeit a little strangely.  (the player with more cards keeps warring against the same face value.

So, that's a start.  But everyone else is right, you really need to provide more information about how it broke so that we can better help you.  Lord knows if these fixes will do everything, but they'll be a step in the right direction.

Oh, also don't forget to set the war card values back to zero when you're done, or your wars will escalate (which could be an interesting feature, actually).